# Model has not yet been built when running model.summary() even though input layer is defined

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, conv-neural-network

I am relatively new to ml, and am building a CNN+LSTM Model for video classification, but ran into an error while trying to run model.summary().

A bit of background on the model itself: I am passing (48, 48, 1) grayscale images through with a batch size of 15 using ImageDataGenerator. It is binary classification (either a or b).

I am encountering one error with model.summary(), and when trying to fix this error, am running into more errors.

Here is the code for my model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

cnn = Sequential()

num_timesteps = 2

# 1st conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 2nd conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(128,(5,5), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 3rd conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 4th conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# flatten
cnn.add(Flatten())

# fully connected 1
cnn.add(Dense(256))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

#fully connected 2
cnn.add(Dense(512))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))


model = Sequential()

model.add(Reshape((1, 48, 48, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(num_timesteps, 48, 48, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(num_timesteps, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

#model.build(input_shape)

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

The error I am receiving is:

> This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.

I have specified the input for the model, so I am confused as to why I am getting this error.

I have tried to fix this error by doing the following things:

I have added model.build(), but that only brings up a subsequent error later on when I try to run model.predict(). It states that *"WARNING:tensorflow:Sequential models without an `input_shape` passed to the first layer cannot reload their optimizer state. As a result, your model isstarting with a freshly initialized optimizer"*, before giving the following error:

> TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType uint8 not in list of allowed values: float16, bfloat16, float32, float64, int32

I have also tried removing the reshape layer which fixes the model.summary() error, but that gives a different error when running model.fit():

> Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_108_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (15, 48, 48, 1)

I am also confused as to why I am getting an error here as when looking at the output shape in the output of model.summary, there are clearly 5 dimensions (None, 2, 48, 48, 64). To my understanding "None" gets replaced with the batch size which is 15.

So my understanding of all of these errors is that by fixing the first error with the input_shape in model.summary() or the error with model.fit(), the rest of the errors will be fixed

Thank you for taking the time to read through this, and any help with fixing these errors would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The input_shape has to be specified to the first layer of each model, you are not doing that.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy could you please explain where else I should specify the first layer or how I should do it differently. I have specified it for the CNN, should I also specify for the LSTM? If it isn't too much trouble, could you give your answer as an "Answer" instead of a comment? Thanks!

Comment: In your CNN the first layer (Conv2D) should have a input_shape, and in your LSTM, the Reshape layer is the first layer, so this one should have an input_shape

Comment: Thanks, by changing it to model.add(Reshape((1, 48, 48, 1), input_shape=(48, 48, 1))) I was able to solve the error!